# String input to Binary output Java

Tags: java, binary

Hi all I am trying to write an encryption program which converts each letter of the input to a 7 byte binary number before outputting. I am using the .toBinaryString method for this so please do not suggest another solution, the problem I am having is that it only converts the first character of the string! any help is appreciated here is my attempt

```
public static void convert(String h)
{
    int y =0;
    String f =" ";

    for(int i =0; i<h.length(); i++)
    {
         y = (int)h.charAt(i);
        f = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
    }

    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

I print out y,f to see is it successfully converts it. It works when I input a single character but when I input eg ben it will convert the whole string not letter by letter!

Comment: Pedantic aside: Each character of the input already *is* a 16-bit (not byte) binary number. You're converting each letter to a string that's a textual representation of said number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a new string to `f` on each iteration, so you are left with the last character. You rather need to update the existing string each time.

So, use:

```
f += Integer.toBinaryString(y);
```

in place of:

```
f = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
```

---

Apart from that, consider using a `StringBuilder`, since you are manipulating string inside a for loop.

Comment: Ahhh Dam I can't believe I missed that! Thank you!

Comment: @user1816464. Happens sometimes. But take my last suggestion seriously.

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
String h.....
bytes[] bytesArray = h.getBytes();
```